# If statement executes even if "false" / should not execute at all

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got an html checkbox

```
<label class="top-side-button">
    <span></span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="side_button"  onclick="clickSidebar()">
</label>
```

which shall trigger a sidebar

```
<div class="side-menu">
        <ul id="mySidebar">
        ...
        </ul>
</div>
```

Now i want to manipulate that sidebar with js and jquery.

```
var horizontal = screen.width;
var toggleLeft = document.getElementById("mySidebar");

function clickSidebar() {

if(toggleLeft.style.display === "none"){
    if (horizontal <= 700) {
        toggleLeft.style.display = "block";
        $('.top-side-button span').html('&times;');
        if(toggleLeft.style.display === "block"){                   
            $(".textbox_main").click(function(){
                 $(".top-side-button").trigger('click');
            });
        }
    }else {
        //do something
    }
} else {
    main.style.marginLeft = "0%";
    toggleLeft.style.display = "none";
    if (toggleLeft.style.display === "none") {
        $('.top-side-button span').html('&#9776;');
    }else{
        $('.top-side-button span').html('&times;');
    }
}
}
```

The code is working except the *textbox click event*

If the page is loaded it is processed as follows:

1. `<ul id="mySidebar" style="display: none;"></ul>`
2. first click on the button `<ul id="mySidebar" style="display: block;"></ul>`
3. close sidebar by clicking on the mainbox `<ul id="mySidebar" style="display: none; width=80%;"></ul>`
4. however, clicking again on the main textbox the sidebar get displayed again even though the `toggleLeft.style.display` is "none"

The console.log of `toggleLeft.style.display` puts out something like:

1. none
2. block
3. none & block
4. none, block, none

   10. block, none, block, none, block, ..., none

There apparently is some mistake but I don't know how to solve it. I also don't get why the event even executes because the `function clickSidebar()` is not executed anymore after closing the sidebar.

I also tried to use the status un/checked of the checkbox but it did not make a difference which I don't understand.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated

Comment: separate state out from the DOM elements

Comment: Get the click event attaching out of the outer event handler. every time you check/uncheck the checkbox and the conditions are fullfilled, a new handler will be attached.

Comment: put a console.log(toggleLeft.style.display) before your 'if'. It is impossible  to go inside if-closure for a false condition. I would suggest you change your question title ASAP

Comment: `$(".textbox_main").click(function(){` whats this for & why you are keeping it there, it would just keep re-registering that way

Comment: at JohnPan: I would change the title but I don't understand the problem exactly until now so I am not able to edit the title. Any suggestions for the title will be accepted
@Teemu: I still don't get why this happens "every time you check/uncheck the checkbox and the conditions are fullfilled, a new handler will be attached."
/ what you have said exactly means.

Comment: It means exactly what was written ... If `toggleLeft` is hidden and `horizontal` is smaller than or equal to 700, your code attaches (`$(".textbox_main").click(...)`) a new click listener to every element `.textbox_main` selector finds, every time you check or uncheck the checkbox, which has this functon attached as the click event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, actually an easy solution but could not think of it.

I deleted:

```
if(toggleLeft.style.display === "block"){                   
        $(".textbox_main").click(function(){
             $(".top-side-button").trigger('click');
        });
 }
```

and outside the `function clickSidebar` added

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $(".textbox_main").click(function(){
        if(toggleLeft.style.display === "block"){   
            $(".top-side-button").trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
```